# OpenSSL library path not found in Aure IOT hub installation

Tags: ssl, cmake, openssl, beagleboneblack, azure-iot-sdk

I am installing the Aure IOT hub on a beagle bone board. During the installation I see an error of Cmake mentioning that Cmake is not able to find the OpenSSL library and directory path.

I followed couple of posts on Stack Overflow, they mentioned about adding the path manually to Cmake using the -D option (`-DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local/ssl`), but I am not able to find that path (/usr/local/ssl) to OpenSSL on my beagle bone. I see only an SSL folder in `/etc`, also I do not see the lib folder in `/etc/ssl` which is needed to add the SSL library path (`-DOPENSSL_LIBRARIES=/usr/local/ssl/lib`).

Please guide me in resolving this issue.

Thanks

Comment: `I see only an SSL folder in /etc, but I need the lib folder also.` - You need SSl *development* package, as usual.

Comment: Have you checked [this tutorial](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-device-ecosystem/blob/master/get_started/debian-beaglebone-black-c.md#31-build-sdk-and-sample) and installed OpenSSL library?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT yes that is correct, I am following that tutorial to install Azure IoT SDK on my beaglebone. It is so much frustrating to see that OpenSSL error.

Comment: @Tsyvarev how can I install the SSL development package and will it help in resolving the CMAKE errors ?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT Yes I have installed OpenSSL from the build steps mentioned in the link.

Comment: From the related posts I found an answer which worked for getting rid of the OpenSSL error `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`.

Comment: I finally resolved this issue by installing uuid-dev and libssl-dev packages on my beaglebone black board.